# check if program argument equals a single character

Tags: c, gcc

I want to read argument and then compare it with a character:

```
int main (int argc, char *const argv[]) {
    if (argv[1][1] == 'c') {
        client();
    }
    else if (argv[1][1] == 's') {
        server();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works if I type `cc` or `dd`, it also works if I type `ccttttt`. It's just taking the second character, but I'd like it to work only if I type `c`.

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1], "c") == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change argv[1][1] to argv[1][0] and remember in c/c++ all arrays start in '0'

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1]` is a pointer to the first command-line argument.

`argv[1][1]` is the *second* character of that argument.

The first character is `argv[1][0]`. (But first check that `argc >= 2`, i.e., that there actually is a command-line argument.)

Of course this only checks a single character, so it doesn't distinguish between `"c"` and `"cthulhu"`. If that's how you want to handle the argument, that's fine, but you might want to consider a different approach.

Comment: Not even between "c" and "call" ;)

Comment: thank you, and what would you suggest, if i wanted to compare whole string? for example i'd like to check if i typed 'help' or something else